# Changing y axis rotation - changing theme elements of ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

I am making a survival curve using R in R studio. I am trying to rotate the title of my y axis to be horizontal, using guidance from previous posts, and I keep receiving an error message. I am using the following code:

```
my_survplot_c = ggsurvplot(my_survfit_c, data = cohort_comb,                 
           risk.table = TRUE,
           ggtheme = theme_bw(),
           palette = "Dark2",
           conf.int = FALSE,
           pval=FALSE,
           legend.title = "OTC Offered", legend.labs = c("No", "Yes"),
           ylab = "Proportion without POI", xlab = "Time (years)")

my_survplot_c + ylab("Proportion\nwithout POI") + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))

my_survplot_c
```

The error message  I am receiving is:
Error in my_survplot_c + ylab("Number of\nSolutions") + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0)) :
non-numeric argument to binary operator

I suspect the solution is simple but I am new to R and would appreciate any advice! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could first transform your plot as a ggplot object and your last argument will work :

```
my_survplot_c = ggsurvplot(my_survfit_c, data = cohort_comb,                 
           risk.table = TRUE,
           ggtheme = theme_bw(),
           palette = "Dark2",
           conf.int = FALSE,
           pval=FALSE,
           legend.title = "OTC Offered", legend.labs = c("No", "Yes"),
           ylab = "Proportion without POI", xlab = "Time (years)")$plot

my_survplot_c + ylab("Proportion\nwithout POI") + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))

my_survplot_c
```

Comment: although this might be a solution - it would be nice to make it more visible what exactly you're doing. It took me a good while to see the subsetting operation, and I guess for a newbie it will be really confusing what you did here. maybe separate it out in a new line to make it more obvious.

Comment: Thank you! That has worked. But before making that change, my plot was a life table (Kaplan Meier) and below this was a table with numbers at risk. This number at risk table has disappeared when I use the code you suggested. Do you know why this would be? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Great ! Could you edit your post by adding `dput(head(my_survfit_c))` ? I currently don't know what is going on but I can have a look :)